# Why do my custom javascript modules not work anymore after updating bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, updating, theming

I have some custom javascript modules in my Drupal site that worked perfect. Yesterday I performed an update for bootstrap and unfortunately the custom javascript modules doesn't work.
I get bellow errors to chrome developer tool console:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

If you want to see the problem, you can here: http://www.neashmera.gr/

Comment: How did you update your site? Did you use jQuery Update?

Comment: what jquery version you are using right now?

Comment: I have only update the bootstrap theme of drupal. I use jQuery Update module.

Comment: In jQuery Update module I have 1.7 JQUERY VERSION

Comment: show up your custom code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

locate the javascript file where you have your error throwing code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){var weatherAPI='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';var data={q:"Athens",units:"metric",appid:"b0847a3de80121926a9f428c35f611f8"};function showWeather(weatherReport){var iconURL='http://openweathermap.org/img/w/'+ weatherReport.weather[0].icon+'.png';var imgE=document.createElement('img');$("#open-weather").attr('src',iconURL);$('#temperature').html('&#913;&#952;&#942;&#957;&#945; '+ weatherReport.main.temp+'&#176;');}
$.getJSON(weatherAPI,data,showWeather);});;function dateAndTime(){var date=new Date();var day;var dayOfMonth=date.getDate();var month;var h=date.getHours();var m=date.getMinutes();var s=date.getSeconds();switch(date.getDay()){case 0:day="&#922;&#965;&#961;&#953;&#945;&#954;&#942;";break;case 1:day="&#916;&#949;&#965;&#964;&#941;&#961;&#945;";break;case 2:day="&#932;&#961;&#943;&#964;&#951;";break;case 3:day="&#932;&#949;&#964;&#940;&#961;&#964;&#951;";break;case 4:day="&#928;&#941;&#956;&#960;&#964;&#951;";break;case 5:day="&#928;&#945;&#961;&#945;&#963;&#949;&#954;&#965;&#942;";break;case 6:day="&#931;&#940;&#946;&#946;&#945;&#964;&#959;";break;}
switch(date.getMonth()){case 0:month="&#921;&#945;&#957;&#959;&#965;&#945;&#961;&#943;&#959;&#965;";break;case 1:month="&#934;&#949;&#946;&#961;&#959;&#965;&#945;&#961;&#943;&#959;&#965;";break;case 2:month="&#924;&#945;&#961;&#964;&#943;&#959;&#965;";break;case 3:month="&#913;&#960;&#961;&#953;&#955;&#943;&#959;&#965;";break;case 4:month="&#924;&#945;&#970;&#959;&#965;";break;case 5:month="&#921;&#959;&#965;&#957;&#943;&#959;&#965;";break;case 6:month="&#921;&#959;&#965;&#955;&#943;&#959;&#965;";break;case 7:month="&#913;&#965;&#947;&#959;&#973;&#963;&#964;&#959;&#965;";break;case 8:month="&#931;&#949;&#960;&#964;&#949;&#956;&#946;&#961;&#943;&#959;&#965;";break;case 9:month="&#927;&#954;&#964;&#969;&#946;&#961;&#943;&#959;&#965;";break;case 10:month="&#925;&#959;&#949;&#956;&#946;&#961;&#943;&#959;&#965;";break;case 11:month="&#916;&#949;&#954;&#949;&#956;&#946;&#961;&#943;&#959;&#965;";break;}
if(h<10){h="0"+ h;}
if(m<10){m="0"+ m;}
if(s<10){s="0"+ s;}
var time=h+":"+ m+":"+ s;$('#time-now').html(time);setTimeout('dateAndTime();','1000');var myDate=day+', '+ dayOfMonth+" "+ month;$('#date-now').html(myDate);return true;};
```

then wrap it with

```
(function($) {
..
})(jQuery);
```

or replace the *$* sign with *jQuery*

Comment: It works :) Thank you very much I spent a lot of hours to fix it